# How to check if objects colliders are touching unity 3D (except from oncollisionenter)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a merge script pretty much they have a enum of small,medium,big,bigger

my script pretty much when they touch checks if they are the same type if so it makes the one thats higher Y positon inactive and makes the one it merge with enlarge/change material to the new type eg small would go to medium, if one small keeps spawning in  eventually you would get for example 3 mediums touching each other and no be processed i think its because im processing other stuff and blocking more collisions are the others are colliding (preventing 3 small ones merging if they all touch at same time), to get this issue i have 5 spawners that spawn all the objects into a container so lets say there is a medium one and small one touching then a small one hits the other small one it will change to medium but as there still touching it wont trigger on collison calls

Here is my code:

[here you see them touching and not merging again they will only merge if move and triggered again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbeMO.png)

https://pastebin.com/5J3sjCHx

this is where the initial call is for when hit

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if(this.ObjectType == ObjectSize.Bigger) { return; }
 
        var ObjectCollidedWith = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<MergeableObject>();
        if (ObjectCollidedWith)
        {
            CollisionCheck(ObjectCollidedWith);
        }
    }`
```

expect everything to merge even if they are touching the same types, not sure if is touching is possible,
I do not want the same types to just be touching i want them to merge again afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Use `OnCollisionStay()` instead of `OnCollisionEnter()`.

Comment: Mind to explain why this is a solution?

Comment: @BDL Sorry for the late reply. OnCollisionEnter only triggers on one frame on the initiation of the collision. OnCollisionStay triggers for every frame during the collision.